# Unordering jobs that are scheduled to run in Control-M

Tags: control-m

How do I stop my running Control-M jobs from executing? Basically I want them to stop running, remove them from the Monitoring view.

Answer (score 0):

in Control-M version 8 you can un-schedule a whole folder by just selecting Manual Order in Order Method. if it's just one specificjob, you can edit the scheduling properties of that job directly and select Manual Order too.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your job and select `"Hold"`. Now `more actions/delete` should be available

Answer (score 0):

at controlM V7 and V8/9 open Desktop/Planning environment, Load the schedule table, select the job individually, at Scheduling tab un-select Months, Verify and Checkin. This method is to disable jobs to load and execute( obviously will not show at monitoring window).
Note: Always at planning load the scheduling table, not individual jobs or subapplications. This will overwrite CtmServer DB.